# How can I select faces by color with Python?

Tags: python, selection-tools

I have imported a VRML model into Blender 2.74 with concentric shells made of polygon faces, each layer of shell is a distinct diffuse color. I am hoping to select faces by their color, then apply translucency or transparency to partly reveal the shell of another color within. I thought python would be a good approach, but when I try bpy.ops.object.select_... I don't see a method to select by color.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need python here. Go to edit mode select a face with your desired color, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and choose `Material`.

Alternatively you can also choose a material in the properties editor and hit select below, to select all faces assigned to that material.

Comment: This is answering a different question than the one which was asked.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I that's not the case. It's selecting the same material, not the color in a material.
What I'm saying is that assign a material to the object, and add a image node to the diffuse color of that material. and u paint on that image texture. Then, u wanna select certain color face. If do the SHIFT-G--->MATERIAL, it's actually gonna select the whole face becasue the whole face is using the same material....